# how to always show left dock in ubuntu gnome desktop on 1604

Tags: 16.04, gnome, ubuntu-dock

I first install ubuntu 16.04 then using the follow command install the ubuntu-gnome-desktop

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

However, after I reboot the system, I can not see the left dock.

Only after I click `Activity` at the left up corner of screen, the left dock can show.

I really like the left dock can always exist, such as it did in default Ubuntu 18.04 or 16.04.

I found that there is no dock relate setting in `Setting`.

How can I let the left dock always exist?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105082/discussion-on-question-by-xu-hui-how-to-always-show-left-dock-in-ubuntu-gnome-de).

Answer (score 3):

Using the following command to configure it:

```
gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```

If there does not exist any setting related to dock, first install `dash-to-dock`.

References:

- https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/
- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1300/ubuntu-dock/